# Create an array of values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with not unique names like below:

```
|-|---------------------|------------------|
| |          A          |         B        |
|-|---------------------|------------------|
|1|         John        |    01.01.1900    |
|-|---------------------|------------------|
|2|         Adam        |    01.02.1900    |
|-|---------------------|------------------|
|3|         John        |    01.03.1900    |
|-|---------------------|------------------|
|4|         Jane        |    01.04.1900    |
|-|---------------------|------------------|
```

And I have another table with unique names like:

```
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| |          A          |     B    |     C    |     D    |     E    |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|1|         Name        |01.01.1900|01.02.1900|01.03.1900|01.04.1900|
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|2|         John        |          |          |          |          |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|3|         Adam        |          |          |          |          |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|4|         Jane        |          |          |          |          |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Now I want to highlight the cells in the second table if name and date match with the first table and make it look like:

```
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| |          A          |     B    |     C    |     D    |     E    |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|1|         Name        |01.01.1900|01.02.1900|01.03.1900|01.04.1900|
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|2|         John        |    1     |          |    1     |          |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|3|         Adam        |          |    1     |          |          |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|4|         Jane        |          |          |          |    1     |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

I've tried using the `FILTER()` function in `B2` cell (for John only):
=`IF(B$1=FILTER('dates'!$B$2:$B$4;'dates'!$A$2:$A$4=$A2);1;0)` where "dates" is name of the sheet with the first table and then expanding it to other cells in the 2nd row, but when I do it I get the following:

```
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| |          A          |     B    |     C    |     D    |     E    |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|1|         Name        |01.01.1900|01.02.1900|01.03.1900|01.04.1900|
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|2|         John        |    1     |    0     |    0     |    0     |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|3|         Adam        |    0     |    0     |    1     |    0     |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|4|         Jane        |          |          |          |          |
|-|---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you have `XLOOKUP()` you might have got `FILTER()`?

Comment: I did not use it. So I should build an array with XLOOKUP and then use FILTER?

Comment: `FILTER()` will do =)

Comment: @JvdV thank you, that worked, but it spills the formula to cells below. Do you know how I can disable it? The formula is
`=IF(I1=FILTER(B2:B40;A2:A40=C4);1;0)`

Comment: Fixed it with `@`

Comment: @JvdV, nope, it did not work, `=@IF(I1=FILTER(B2:B40;A2:A40=C4);1;0)` returns only first value when expanding the formula

Comment: Yes `@` is the implicit intersection operator. It will make ExcelO365 handle a formula like previous version of Excel and therefor only return a single value. What you should do is nest `FILTER()` into the next function you want, because you mentioned: *"Ideally I need to build an array of values, for example for John it will be {01.01.1900, 03.03.1900} and compare cell value with this array."*. So now you got to think, how and why you want to compare that cell value. Without a better formulated question it's a guessing game for me what it is you really want done.

Comment: That's not making it any clearer to me what it is you want.

Comment: @JvdV I've nested the FILTER into IF function. There are 2 sheets: the first one with table from question and the second one is with calendar
Formula in `I4` looks like `=IF(I$1=FILTER('dates'!$B$2:$B$40;'dates'!$A$2:$A$40=$A4);1;0)`
Cell `A4` = `John`; cell `I1` = `01.01.1900`. `'dates'!$A$2:$A$40` is list of names from the question and `'dates'!$B$2:$B$40` is list of dates. But when using this formula I got 1 in cell `I4` and 0 in `I5`. Next I expand the formula to next cell `J4`. Cell `J1`=03.03.1900, but `J4`=0 and `J5`=1.

Comment: You have to change your question, visualize what you are doing including your wanted result. That will make things easier to understand. See [ask] a question with an [mcve] for some general guidelines.

Comment: @JvdV thank you. I've updated the question, hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, your edit makes your question a lot more clearer, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,E$1)
```

Drag down and right.

Also, since you happen to have Excel O365, you can do the whole matrix in a single go with the following formula in `E2`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,D2:D4,B1:B4,E1:H1)
```

Now the rest of the matrix will auto-fill.